# Java-How to extract content of my running jar into a directory?

Tags: java, jar, path, directory, extract

My goal is to extract a folder inside my running Jar to a specific location.

I can copy files from a folder to another, with the same code, but when it comes to the jar, it does not work:
Take a look at the jar's picture:

[Jar Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sk1Ln.png)

And now at the code

[Code Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sH4MI.png)

If you cannot read the code:

```
File f1;
        f1 = new File("/Kingdoms/");

        File f3 = new File("C:\\Cavedog\\Kingdoms");
        move(f1, f3);
```

I assume the problem is at the f1 path, and that's what I need to know. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

To *read* a resource from a .jar, you might use something like this:

```
BufferedReader r = 
  new BufferedReader(
    new InputStreamReader(
       getClass().getResourceAsStream("Kingdoms/myfile.png") ));
```

Comment: Thank you but I dont need the InputStreamReader but the PATH itself :C
Or Ill need to re-write all my codes.

Answer (score 1):

Read the file into a byte[] using paulsm4's method, then write that byte[] to whatever file you want to move it to